sklearn pipeline (de)serialization in DAG format
Consider sklearn pipeline which contains only the following steps: Pipeline, FeatureUnion, Transformer.
I can express an arbitrary sklearn pipeline in a form of DAG, where nodes correspond to data state and edges correspond to pipeline steps. From sklearn example (assume ColumnSelector is implemented) the following pipeline:
column_trans = make_column_transformer(
  (OneHotEncoder(), ['city']),
  (CountVectorizer(), 'title'),
  remainder=MinMaxScaler())

can be rewritten as:
FeatureUnion([
  ("cat_ohe", Pipeline([
    ("selector", ColumnSelector(["city"])),
    ("ohe", OneHotEncoder())
  ])),
  ("cat_cv", Pipeline([
    ("selector", ColumnSelector("titile")),
    ("cv", CountVectorizer())
  ])),
  ("rem", Pipeline([
    ("selector", ColumnSelector(exclude=["city", "title"])),
    ("cv", MinMaxScaler())
  ])),
])


and embedded into sql table:
edge_id,source_node_id,target_node_id,transformer
0,0,1,'ColumnSelector'
1,1,2,'OneHotEncoder'
2,2,3,'Concat'
3,0,4,'ColumnSelector'
4,4,5,'CountVectorizer'
5,5,3,'Concat'
6,0,6,'ColumnSelector'
7,6,7,'MinMaxScaler'
8,7,3,'Concat'

I want to implement serialization and deserialization of the pipeline. Below is my attempt on that, please provide comments on how to improve deserialization and how to implement serialization.
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline, FeatureUnion, make_pipeline, make_union
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA, TruncatedSVD
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, Normalizer


edges = [
    (1, 1, 2, SimpleImputer()),
    (2, 2, 3, TruncatedSVD()),
    (3, 2, 4, PCA()),
    (4, 3, 5, StandardScaler()),
    (5, 4, 6, None),
    (6, 5, 6, None),
    (7, 6, 7, Normalizer())
]



def parse_pipeline(node):
    steps = []

    while True:
        current_edges = [e for e in edges if e[1] == node]

        if len(current_edges) == 0:  # terminal node
            if len(steps) == 0:
                return None
            elif len(steps) == 1:
                return steps[0]
            else:
                return make_pipeline(*steps)
        elif len(current_edges) == 1:  # sequential node
            node = current_edges[0][2]

            if current_edges[0][3] is None:  # concat node
                node = current_edges[0][2]
                break
            else:
                steps.append(current_edges[0][3])
        else:  # parallel node
            parallel_steps = []
            terminal_nodes = []

            for e in current_edges:
                p, n = parse_pipeline(e[2])

                if p is None:
                    parallel_steps.append(e[3])
                else:
                    parallel_steps.append(make_pipeline(e[3], p))

                terminal_nodes.append(n)
            
            # check terminal nodes equal
            assert len(set(terminal_nodes)) == 1

            if len(parallel_steps) == 1:
                s = parallel_steps[0]
            else:
                s = make_union(*parallel_steps)

            steps.append(s)
            node = terminal_nodes[0]

    if len(steps) == 0:
        return None, node
    elif len(steps) == 1:
        return steps[0], node
    else:
        return make_pipeline(*steps), node


p = parse_pipeline(1)
print(p)

